# Find single letter words with spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

There is a sentence:

```
Ala ma kota i psa.
```

We can see that the whole sentence is in one line but if we place it in small div it will change.

In Polish language we have single letter words like 'i' (and) or 'w' (in, with) etc.

Those words/letters don't look good when left at the end of line so we place them on the next one:

```
Ala ma kota 
i psa.
```

instead of:

```
Ala ma kota i
psa.
```

Problem:

I am trying to find all single letters so I can replace the ending space with nobreak space. That should do the trick.

Comment: do you want to find any single letter?

Comment: Single letters with space before and after it, e.g. spaceLETTERspace

Comment: maybe replacing the space after *any* single letter is not what you want. for example the v in "Rocky V" is better left next to rocky than heading the next line. maybe you could explicitly list the single letter words in polish which you want to eventually head a line.

Comment: That is actually great idea. Often used conjunctions: i, w, o.

Comment: please update your question with that, and include what behaviour you expect with punctuation marks (no space).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the discussion, it sounds like the lines are not already split, and you want to catch only the single-letter words "i", "o", or "w", and you want to allow a comma after the word. Let's allow semicolon too, just to make it more interesting.

You might do something like this:

```
def no_orphan( str )
    str.gsub( /( [iow][,;]?) /, '\1&nbsp;' )
end
```

Example in irb:

```
irb(main):001:0> def no_orphan( str )
irb(main):002:1>     str.gsub( /( [iow][,;]?) /, '\1&nbsp;' )
irb(main):003:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> no_orphan 'Ala ma kota i psa.'
=> "Ala ma kota i&nbsp;psa."
irb(main):005:0> no_orphan 'Ala ma kota i, psa.'
=> "Ala ma kota i,&nbsp;psa."
irb(main):006:0> no_orphan 'Ala ma kota i; psa.'
=> "Ala ma kota i;&nbsp;psa."
irb(main):007:0> no_orphan 'Test Rocky V with space.'
=> "Test Rocky V with space."
irb(main):008:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to match all single words at the end:

```
\b[a-zA-Z]$     //or \b\p{L}$
```

And then you can apply your trick..

See [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/NUTX0VzUzk)

**Edit:** If you want to match the spaceLetterSpace at the end use the following:

```
\s+[a-zA-Z]\b[^a-zA-Z]*
```

See [DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/bhnJfPV5Wj)

Comment: those are only ascii letters. maybe in polish there are more possibilities.

Comment: also, he wants to replace normal spaces *after* single letters. it is not at the end.

Comment: You will not find them at the end of sentence with full stop following but they might have coma like: i, . Forgot to add that. 
Can be only ascii letters.

Comment: I updated the text a little bit. http://rubular.com/r/cfwjuTtRKU
It should grab 'i' letter with surrounding spaces.

Comment: Works. Now I don't know which is better. Yours or Michael's.

Comment: @DominikSpisak Test both regexes with `Ala ma kota i.` and decide by yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

`\s(\w[,;]?) *\n` will match a single letter at the end of a line. You can replace that by `"\n"+group(1)`

Comment: he wants to replace the space after the single letter.